# Is there a way to get the Android (free) apps download data?

Tags: android

To download the Android app sales data the below api is a good way to automatically download and analyze the data. But unfortunately, this api doesn't report on the number of free app downloads and reports only the apps that cost something($). Is there a way to get the free app downloads data without leaning on screen scraping? There must be a better way to do this right? Can someone guide me to the right solution. Thanks.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Order_Report_Tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get data for your own apps or for someone else's?  All of the information you will need about your own applications published in the Android Market will be located on the Android developer dashboard:

https://market.android.com/publish/Home?pli=1

Comment: My own apps. I saw that data but its showing the aggregate info but is there a way to automatically download that data in a csv with a daily break down of the numbers.